# HTML E-Mail: Removing border from table in Outlook 2007

Tags: html, css, email, outlook

I'm am trying to get rid of table borders. It displays fine in GMAIL Webapp but Outlook just uses black default borders. How can I get rid of them?

```
<TABLE style="BORDER-TOP: 0px; BORDER-RIGHT: 0px; BORDER-COLLAPSE: collapse; BORDER-BOTTOM: 0px; MARGIN: 0px auto; BORDER-SPACING: 0; BORDER-LEFT: 0px" cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0 rules=none width="95%" border=0 frame=void>
    <TR border="0" cellPadding="0" cellSpacing="0">
        <TH style="OVERFLOW: hidden; FONT-SIZE: 12px; BORDER-TOP: 0px solid; FONT-FAMILY: Arial, sans-serif; BORDER-RIGHT: 0px solid; VERTICAL-ALIGN: top; BORDER-BOTTOM: 0px solid; WORD-BREAK: normal; FONT-WEIGHT: bold; COLOR: #ffffff; PADDING-BOTTOM: 10px; PADDING-TOP: 10px; PADDING-LEFT: 5px; BORDER-LEFT: 0px solid; PADDING-RIGHT: 5px; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #00349a" border="0" cellPadding="0" cellSpacing="0">OEM-Nr.</TH>
        <TH style="OVERFLOW: hidden; FONT-SIZE: 12px; BORDER-TOP: 0px solid; FONT-FAMILY: Arial, sans-serif; BORDER-RIGHT: 0px solid; VERTICAL-ALIGN: top; BORDER-BOTTOM: 0px solid; WORD-BREAK: normal; FONT-WEIGHT: bold; COLOR: #ffffff; PADDING-BOTTOM: 10px; PADDING-TOP: 10px; PADDING-LEFT: 5px; BORDER-LEFT: 0px solid; PADDING-RIGHT: 5px; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #00349a" border="0" cellPadding="0" cellSpacing="0">Bezeichnung</TH>
        <TH style="OVERFLOW: hidden; FONT-SIZE: 12px; BORDER-TOP: 0px solid; FONT-FAMILY: Arial, sans-serif; BORDER-RIGHT: 0px solid; VERTICAL-ALIGN: top; BORDER-BOTTOM: 0px solid; WORD-BREAK: normal; FONT-WEIGHT: bold; COLOR: #ffffff; PADDING-BOTTOM: 10px; PADDING-TOP: 10px; PADDING-LEFT: 5px; BORDER-LEFT: 0px solid; PADDING-RIGHT: 5px; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #00349a" border="0" cellPadding="0" cellSpacing="0">Preis</TH></TR>
    <TR border="0" cellPadding="0" cellSpacing="0">
        <TD style="OVERFLOW: hidden; FONT-SIZE: 12px; BORDER-TOP: 0px solid; FONT-FAMILY: Arial, sans-serif; BORDER-RIGHT: 0px solid; VERTICAL-ALIGN: top; BORDER-BOTTOM: 0px solid; WORD-BREAK: normal; FONT-WEIGHT: bold; PADDING-BOTTOM: 10px; PADDING-TOP: 10px; PADDING-LEFT: 5px; BORDER-LEFT: 0px solid; PADDING-RIGHT: 5px" border="0" cellPadding="0" cellSpacing="0">DCP8110DNG1</TD>
        <TD style="OVERFLOW: hidden; FONT-SIZE: 12px; BORDER-TOP: 0px solid; FONT-FAMILY: Arial, sans-serif; BORDER-RIGHT: 0px solid; VERTICAL-ALIGN: top; BORDER-BOTTOM: 0px solid; WORD-BREAK: normal; FONT-WEIGHT: bold; PADDING-BOTTOM: 10px; PADDING-TOP: 10px; PADDING-LEFT: 5px; BORDER-LEFT: 0px solid; PADDING-RIGHT: 5px" border="0" cellPadding="0" cellSpacing="0">Brother DCP-8110DN</TD>
        <TD style="OVERFLOW: hidden; FONT-SIZE: 12px; BORDER-TOP: 0px solid; FONT-FAMILY: Arial, sans-serif; BORDER-RIGHT: 0px solid; VERTICAL-ALIGN: top; BORDER-BOTTOM: 0px solid; WORD-BREAK: normal; FONT-WEIGHT: bold; COLOR: #00349a; PADDING-BOTTOM: 10px; PADDING-TOP: 10px; PADDING-LEFT: 5px; BORDER-LEFT: 0px solid; PADDING-RIGHT: 5px" border="0" cellPadding="0" cellSpacing="0">239,00 &euro;</TD>
    </TR>
    <TR border="0" cellPadding="0" cellSpacing="0">
        <TD style="OVERFLOW: hidden; FONT-SIZE: 12px; BORDER-TOP: 0px solid; FONT-FAMILY: Arial, sans-serif; BORDER-RIGHT: 0px solid; VERTICAL-ALIGN: top; BORDER-BOTTOM: 0px solid; WORD-BREAK: normal; FONT-WEIGHT: bold; PADDING-BOTTOM: 10px; PADDING-TOP: 10px; PADDING-LEFT: 5px; BORDER-LEFT: 0px solid; PADDING-RIGHT: 5px; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #edf4fc" border="0" cellPadding="0" cellSpacing="0">HL3142CWG1</TD>
        <TD style="OVERFLOW: hidden; FONT-SIZE: 12px; BORDER-TOP: 0px solid; FONT-FAMILY: Arial, sans-serif; BORDER-RIGHT: 0px solid; VERTICAL-ALIGN: top; BORDER-BOTTOM: 0px solid; WORD-BREAK: normal; FONT-WEIGHT: bold; PADDING-BOTTOM: 10px; PADDING-TOP: 10px; PADDING-LEFT: 5px; BORDER-LEFT: 0px solid; PADDING-RIGHT: 5px; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #edf4fc" border="0" cellPadding="0" cellSpacing="0">Brother HL-3142CW</TD>
        <TD style="OVERFLOW: hidden; FONT-SIZE: 12px; BORDER-TOP: 0px solid; FONT-FAMILY: Arial, sans-serif; BORDER-RIGHT: 0px solid; VERTICAL-ALIGN: top; BORDER-BOTTOM: 0px solid; WORD-BREAK: normal; FONT-WEIGHT: bold; COLOR: #00349a; PADDING-BOTTOM: 10px; PADDING-TOP: 10px; PADDING-LEFT: 5px; BORDER-LEFT: 0px solid; PADDING-RIGHT: 5px; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #edf4fc" border="0" cellPadding="0" cellSpacing="0">109,00 &euro;</TD>
    </TR>
    <TR border="0" cellPadding="0" cellSpacing="0">
        <TD style="OVERFLOW: hidden; FONT-SIZE: 12px; BORDER-TOP: 0px solid; FONT-FAMILY: Arial, sans-serif; BORDER-RIGHT: 0px solid; VERTICAL-ALIGN: top; BORDER-BOTTOM: 0px solid; WORD-BREAK: normal; FONT-WEIGHT: bold; PADDING-BOTTOM: 10px; PADDING-TOP: 10px; PADDING-LEFT: 5px; BORDER-LEFT: 0px solid; PADDING-RIGHT: 5px" border="0" cellPadding="0" cellSpacing="0">HL5450DNG1</TD>
        <TD style="OVERFLOW: hidden; FONT-SIZE: 12px; BORDER-TOP: 0px solid; FONT-FAMILY: Arial, sans-serif; BORDER-RIGHT: 0px solid; VERTICAL-ALIGN: top; BORDER-BOTTOM: 0px solid; WORD-BREAK: normal; FONT-WEIGHT: bold; PADDING-BOTTOM: 10px; PADDING-TOP: 10px; PADDING-LEFT: 5px; BORDER-LEFT: 0px solid; PADDING-RIGHT: 5px" border="0" cellPadding="0" cellSpacing="0">Brother HL-5450DN</TD>
        <TD style="OVERFLOW: hidden; FONT-SIZE: 12px; BORDER-TOP: 0px solid; FONT-FAMILY: Arial, sans-serif; BORDER-RIGHT: 0px solid; VERTICAL-ALIGN: top; BORDER-BOTTOM: 0px solid; WORD-BREAK: normal; FONT-WEIGHT: bold; COLOR: #00349a; PADDING-BOTTOM: 10px; PADDING-TOP: 10px; PADDING-LEFT: 5px; BORDER-LEFT: 0px solid; PADDING-RIGHT: 5px" border="0" cellPadding="0" cellSpacing="0">149,00 &euro;</TD></TR>
    <TR border="0" cellPadding="0" cellSpacing="0">
        <TD style="OVERFLOW: hidden; FONT-SIZE: 12px; BORDER-TOP: 0px solid; FONT-FAMILY: Arial, sans-serif; BORDER-RIGHT: 0px solid; VERTICAL-ALIGN: top; BORDER-BOTTOM: 0px solid; WORD-BREAK: normal; FONT-WEIGHT: bold; PADDING-BOTTOM: 10px; PADDING-TOP: 10px; PADDING-LEFT: 5px; BORDER-LEFT: 0px solid; PADDING-RIGHT: 5px; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #edf4fc" border="0" cellPadding="0" cellSpacing="0">HLL8250CDNG1</TD>
        <TD style="OVERFLOW: hidden; FONT-SIZE: 12px; BORDER-TOP: 0px solid; FONT-FAMILY: Arial, sans-serif; BORDER-RIGHT: 0px solid; VERTICAL-ALIGN: top; BORDER-BOTTOM: 0px solid; WORD-BREAK: normal; FONT-WEIGHT: bold; PADDING-BOTTOM: 10px; PADDING-TOP: 10px; PADDING-LEFT: 5px; BORDER-LEFT: 0px solid; PADDING-RIGHT: 5px; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #edf4fc" border="0" cellPadding="0" cellSpacing="0">Brother HL-L8250CDN</TD>
        <TD style="OVERFLOW: hidden; FONT-SIZE: 12px; BORDER-TOP: 0px solid; FONT-FAMILY: Arial, sans-serif; BORDER-RIGHT: 0px solid; VERTICAL-ALIGN: top; BORDER-BOTTOM: 0px solid; WORD-BREAK: normal; FONT-WEIGHT: bold; COLOR: #00349a; PADDING-BOTTOM: 10px; PADDING-TOP: 10px; PADDING-LEFT: 5px; BORDER-LEFT: 0px solid; PADDING-RIGHT: 5px; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #edf4fc" border="0" cellPadding="0" cellSpacing="0">149,00 &euro;</TD>
    </TR>
</TABLE>
```

I'm using Supermailer to code. It capitalized `HTML`/`CSS` semantics and changes them on export. I have no idea why, but it usually works.

Comment: If you have both style border:0 and an attribute border=0 (and even frame=void; very thorough), and they're still being overwritten, I'm not sure there's much you can do. Have you tried `!important` on the styles?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, I got the solution. Somehow removing every border css command and simply relying on border=0 worked. I hate coding newsletters. They make no sense whatsoever.

Thank you though, appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

Change `solid` in border-top with `hidden`. 
I should put a comment for this but still can't for lack of reputation.

Ref: [Css Border Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_border.asp)